# Java partial enum backed by the database

Tags: java, database, enum

I have following problem:

need to use enum in my java code, since I'll have to ask in my business logic things like if(someting == enumname.VALUE_ENUM){... but I don't have all the enum types at the compile time - that is I have them but there is too many enum types that I won't use in my business logic except in cases where I need to loop over all of the enum values for(enumname var : enumname.value()){...

This seems more like the real entity then (since in DB it has an Id and a lot more properties), but it looks ugly to type if(something == object.getByString("VALUE_ENUM"))

Is there some more pedant way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found solution here if anybody needs it...

http://niceideas.ch/roller2/badtrash/entry/java_create_enum_instances_dynamically

and this is the one with compile-time solution:

https://bojanv55.wordpress.com/2015/05/25/java-dynamic-enums/